# Need to write shown XAML code into code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to rewrite the following code block in the Code behind file of my `UserControl`.

I am having problems with this part of the code,

```
<TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="dtViewModel" DataType="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="txtBlockItem" Text="{Binding Fullname}" MouseRightButtonUp="TextBlock_MouseRightButtonUp">

                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

As I cannot reference the HierarchicalDataTemlate or the Child `TextBlock` by the `x:Name` i have set, also having problems with the `DataType` property.

Any pointers in the right direction or help is appreciated as always.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the data binding with code behind? Surely that's a backwards step?

Comment: Yes i am, i know its not the right way to do it. But it needs to be a fast fix until the logic of the application gets reworked in the future.

reason for this is because i need to do some manipulation in the code behind for the bindings

Comment: Can you explain further what *manipulation* you need to perform in code behind? Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Why do you need to reference the data templates? Can't you just add your viewmodel classes to the TreeView.Items and the templates will be applied automatically?

Comment: i need the treelist to refresh after making some changes to one of the properties from the datasource. The developer of the application didnt implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event correctly so i want to manually set the datacontext again for the HierarchicalDataTemplate.

should be easy fix for now, but i cannot seem to reference the control and need to know how to access the HierarchicalDataTemplate by name or other means - This will get fixed in the future with the correct way of binding this, just need a quick fix for now.

Comment: Sounds like you could just rebind your whole object graph to achieve what you want. If you know when the refresh should happen just refresh everything.

Comment: If i rebind the entire Treeview i will need to do the same for all sub contents bindings, and that will lead to flickering of the entire tree when its updated, by just rebinding the textblock im hoping to avoid this issue. But if it is that difficult to reference the HierarchicalDataTemplate, i might just invest the extra time to do the INotifyPropertyChanged event properly and pass the notification through the layers of viewmodels attached....

Comment: The introduce a wrapper for your nestes object that needs to be updated